# Can we prove uniformization by solving the Yamabe problem directly?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

One version of the [uniformization theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) says that a simply connected complex manifold of (complex) dimension one is biholomorphic to either the unit disc, $\Bbb C$, or $\Bbb{CP}^1$. The proof of this goes through potential theory, ultimately using analysis of subharmonic functions to obtain a biholomorphic map to an open subset of $\Bbb{CP}^1$. Somehow this always seemed like magic to me, so I'm always looking for approaches I find more straightforwardly comprehensible.

On the other hand, because of the relationship between [conformal and complex geometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry) in (real) dimension 2, this is equivalent to solving the [Yamabe problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamabe_problem) (which was originally stated as a generalization of uniformization): does every conformal class of metrics contain one of constant scalar curvature?

Let's quickly recall the formula for the change of scalar curvature in dimension 2 under conformal change of metric:

$$S(e^f g) = e^{-f}(S(g)+\Delta_g f).$$

(Note that here we are using the $g$-Laplacian of $f$.) Fix a metric on either $\Bbb R^2$ or $S^2$. Can we directly solve this equation for the appropriate choice of constant on the LHS, leading to a more Riemannian-flavored solution to the uniformization theorem? (If we can do this without first classifying simply connected surfaces, all the better.) I would also be satisfied with a solution coming from Ricci/Yamabe flow type ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. See the [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02764082) titled "Curvature and uniformization" by Mazzeo and Taylor.

Their abstract:

> We approach the problem of uniformization of general Riemann surfaces
>   through consideration of the curvature equation, and in particular the
>   problem of constructing Poincaré metrics (i.e., complete metrics of
>   constant negative curvature) by solving the equation $Δu-e^{2u}=K_0(z)$ on
>   general open surfaces. A few other topics are discussed, including
>   boundary behavior of the conformal factor $e^{2u}$ giving the Poincare
>   metric when the Riemann surface has smoothly bounded compact closure,
>   and also a curvature equation proof of Koebe's disk theorem.

---

In 2 dimensions, additionally the Ricci flow and Yamabe flow coincide. And indeed it is possible to also obtain a proof of the uniformization theorem from that direction. See the [survey article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4669) by Isenberg, Mazzeo, and Sesum (and references therein) for details.

Comment: These both look great! Thanks!